# App not showing on google playstore when you searched after published

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Our app just published just now on google playstore but if we type the full name it doesn't even show. We have to type the developers name instead in able to show it from the list down below when you scroll down. The app was published via Beta test at the moment, I'm not sure if its the reason or we need to make it publsh to production in able to see. Or do I missed something?

Comment: give it time as google play propagates your APK to their servers.

Comment: Give it sometime. The app will be shown based on the popularity. Till then search your app with your package name.

Comment: It will take around 30 hours to visible on typing by name, else go with package name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also happened to my App before. There are guidelines provided by [Google Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9042516?hl=en) though.

In most cases maybe you are searching in a mobile device that is not supported by your app. Check `targetSdkVersion` in your `AndroidManifest`. In my case it took atleast a day for it to be totally visible in the Google Play Store.